# Order of growth of $\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}(1-a^nz)$ for $0<|a|<1$

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions, hadamard-product

This question is from Conway Complex Analysis, page 287, exercise 9(a).

My attempt: Write the product as $\underset{n}\prod(1-\frac{z}{b^n})$, where $b=1/a$. First note that this entire function has genus $0$ since $\underset{n}\sum \frac{1}{|b|^n}<\infty$ for $|b|>1$. I would like to imitate the argument in this post:
[Order of the entire function: $\prod\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \left(1-\frac{z}{n^k}\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/121398/order-of-the-entire-function-prod-limits-n-1-infty-left1-fracznk) to calculate the order$$\lambda=\underset{r\rightarrow\infty}\limsup\dfrac{\log\log M(r)}{\log r}.$$

But the problem is that $b$ might not be real. Hence the maximum function $M(r)$ is not quite easy to determine (if $b$ is real and positive, then the maximum is attained at $z=-r$ on each circle $\{|z|=r\}$). So I wounder if there is a way to determine explicitly the maximum function $M(r)$ for this particular case.

Comment: You may be interested in the Wikipedia article on [q-Pochhammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).

Comment: @Somos Thanks for the imformation. I was thinking about considering the coefficients of the power series, but having difficulty determining the coefficients. Your comment is really helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to consider the power series of this product. Using q-Pochhammer symbol (link in Somos's comment) the coefficient of $z^n$ is
$$c_n=\dfrac{(-1)^na^{n(n-1)/2}}{\prod_{m=1}^n(1-a^{m})}$$

Then we can compute the order by $\lambda=1/\alpha$, where

$$\alpha=\underset{n\rightarrow \infty}\liminf\dfrac{-\log|c_n|}{n\log n}=\infty$$.

Hence the order is $0$.

Remark: for the case of $\prod(1-\frac{z}{n^k})$, it has order $1/k$. When $k$ gets bigger, the order gets smaller. In our case, the zeros grow exponentially, and thus its order must be smaller than all $1/k$.